# Как запустить одновременно два бесконечных процесса ? (FastAPI)

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

Вобщем я учусь писать тесты и хочу для тестовых нужд, чтобы тест сам запускал сервер uvicorn и ещё один сервер, который запускается из определённой папки командой npm start.

Видимо в синхронном коде это сделать не получится, т.к. uvicorn.run() собственно как и другой сервер, который запускается через npm start  - это процессы бесконечные и как я их местами не менял, запускается всегда один, а до второго дело не доходит.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может быть можно как-то запустить каждую команду в отдельном процессе?

Спасибо!

Мой код:

```
import uvicorn
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(
        'main:app',
        reload=True,
        port=7777
    )
    subprocess.run('cd ~/Desktop/randomfolder && npm start', shell=True)
```

Comment: использовать threads

Comment: @ClarkDevlin на сколько мне известно потоки плохо уживаются в python из-за GIL. Или я что-то путаю?

Comment: @TobaSko как раз именно благодаря GIL они уживаются очень даже хорошо, намного лучше чем в других языках

Comment: А конкретно здесь потоки не нужны, достаточно поставить subprocess.Popen (не run) перед uvicorn.run (потом надо не забыть завершить дочерний процесс, но я в курсе как это правильно сделать в uvicorn)

Comment: @andreymal Вот прямо мистика какая-то с этими потоками в гил. Я уже мильён людей спросил и все разное говорят. Т.е. в итоге многопоточность работает нормально в python?

Comment: @TobaSko конечно нормально, чё б ей не работать-то) С GIL связан лишь один небольшой нюанс — он блокируется на время выполнения Python-кода, и пока Python-код работает, другие потоки, которые тоже хотят выполнить Python-код, приостанавливаются и ждут пока GIL освободится. Если же поток выполняется не в Python-коде, а где-то за его пределами (например, чтение файла с диска, ожидание данных в сокете, какая-нибудь тяжёлая обработка в сишной библиотеке и т.п.), то GIL в такие моменты не блокирутеся и другие потоки могут спокойно работать

Comment: @andreymal  "другие потоки, которые тоже хотят выполнить Python-код," - это имеются в виду потоки, которые хотят выполнить тот же самый python код или уже другой?

Comment: @TobaSko не важно какой код. Тот же или другой.

Comment: @TobaSko любой Python-код, который интерпретируется интерпретатором. GIL нужен, чтобы два одновременно выполняющихся потока случайно не сломали интерпретатор, поэтому существование GIL гарантирует, что Python-код будет выполняться только в одном потоке одновременно. Однако когда управление передаётся из Python-кода например в какую-то сишную библиотеку, она обычно перед началом своей работы освобождает GIL, и таким образом другой Python-код в другом потоке может работать одновременно с этой сишной библиотекой, так что с многопоточностью в питоне всё хорошо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы рассмотрел использование [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).

Устанавливаете его в virtualenv `pip install supervisor` и создаете файл конфигурации [supervisord.conf](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html) типа:

```
[program:uvicorn]
command=uvicorn main:app --port 7777

[program:npm]
command=npm start
directory=~/Desktop/randomfolder
```

Стартуете `supervisord` один раз, и потом запускаете все командой:

```
supervisorctl start all
```

Еще он понимает команды `stop`, `restart`, `status` и [другие](http://supervisord.org/running.html#running-supervisorctl). Умеет перестартовывать приложения если они рухнули и много других полезностей.